# How can I create a radare2 type for a variable-length struct?

Tags: radare2, binary-format, struct

I'm trying to parse a binary file and it has a structure similar to this,

```c
struct foo {
   int64_t count_things;
   int64_t offset_to_thing[count];
   int8_t  bytes[];
   int64_t other fields;
}

struct thing { ; not relevant for example }
```

Now the catch here is that the amount of things is stored in the struct. I assume the whole rest of this is more or less stored as a flexible array member...

```c
struct foo { int64_t count_things; int8_t bytes[size] }
```

But I want more specificity as I want to be able to seek to the location and dump this out. Does Radare give me the tools to parse this kind of variable-length struct?